# I'd like to change the loading logo in Kibana

Tags: css, elasticsearch, kibana

my elk version

- 7.13.0

**I tried changing the logo provided by elastic, but it doesn't work.**

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/custom-logo-kibana-7-10-0-guide/257686

```
Open file
$ sudo nano /usr/share/kibana/src/core/server/rendering/views/template.js

Look for code string:
const logo = _react.default.createElement("svg", {…

Replace this with a base64 or SVG version of your custom logo. I used a base64 image.

Result:
const logo = _react.default.createElement("img", {src:'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAqkAAAK … 5CYII=',width:'100px'});

Locate code block and replace message

}, i18n('core.ui.welcomeMessage', {
defaultMessage: 'Loading Elastic'

Result:
}, i18n('core.ui.welcomeMessage', {
defaultMessage: 'Loading custom_text'
```

The commands above were executed in order.

`sudo nano /usr/share/kibana/src/core/server/rendering/views/template.js`

`const logo = _react.default.createElement("svg", {…`   -->

`const logo = _react.default.createElement("img", {src:'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAqkAAAK … 5CYII=',width:'100px'});`

[image]

**`The guide tells me to replace the code, but I can't see the code.`**

Please tell me specifically.

Again, my kibana version 7.13.0.